# Can't open pattern U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN my application in xcode for some reason during password creation cant access the pattern

Tags: regex, xcode, passwords

Here is the error:
2020-02-11 01:45:02.661017+0800 MedMinder[1730:62710] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching, reason: Can't open pattern U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN (string Password99#, pattern ^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[$@$#!%*?&])([A-Za-z\d$@$#!%*?&]{8,}, case 0, canon 0)'

This is where it is supposed to be accessed

```
import UIKit

class Utilities {

    static func isPasswordValid(_ password : String) -> Bool{

        let passwordTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[$@$#!%*?&])([A-Za-z\\d$@$#!%*?&]{8,}")
        return passwordTest.evaluate(with: password)
    }

}
```

```
let cleanedPassword = passwordTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

    if Utilities.isPasswordValid(cleanedPassword) == false {

        return "Please ensure your password is at least 8 characters, contains a number and a special character."
    }

    return nil
```